# vite js session restore

Tags: jsx, yarnpkg, vite

how can I get back the host server that vite gave me. I closed my pc to take a nap and when I got back terminal was deleted. I created a new terminal but I couldnt find the host server that vite created.

using VScode & yarn.

I used 'yarn vite' in terminal(cmd) to get back to the session but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to use "yarn dev" :)
(to others that dont know)